# Angular : Rxjs : getting error 'You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected' when trying to upload a file

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

I am writing a code to upload files in Angular.

This is my service file :

```
upload(file: File): Observable<any> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
   
    let url = `some_url`;

    if (file) {
      formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    }

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, formData);
    
    return this.http.request(req)
       .pipe(
         catchError((error):any => of({err: error, fileName: file.name, failed: true}))
       )

}
```

And this is my component file :

```
import {
  Observable,
  forkJoin
} from 'rxjs';

fileUploads:any = [];

onFilesSelected(event) {
    if (Array.from(event.target.files).length < 1) {
      return
    }
    this.sendFiles(Array.from(event.target.files)).subscribe({
      next: fileUploads => { this.fileUploads = fileUploads; },
      complete: () => {
         console.log("this.fileUploads", this.fileUploads)
      }
    });
}


sendFiles(files): Observable<unknown> {
    return forkJoin(
      files.map(file => this.uploadService.upload(file))
    );
}
```

I have tried playing around with the above code but i keep getting the same error.
I am on Angular v15 and RxJS v7.5

Answer (score 0):

(You should add typing to your code).
The problem is probably comming from `Array.from(event.target.files)`.
Forkjoin expect a stream but you gave undefined.

Before uploading your files, make a check to be sure that the list of files is not undefined.

```
const listFiles: any[] = Array.from(event.target.files) ?? [];
this.sendFiles(listFiles).subscribe...
```

Comment: i got what you meant but i am still get the same error after making the change @tlvi38

Comment: i had thought of the same and modified the above code to check empty array list, but it didn't work as well. updated the original post with the check